# Generate "Valid" Numbers

Tags: algorithm

I was asked the following question in an interview. I don't have any idea about how to solve this. Any suggestions?

> Given the start and an ending integer as user input,
>   generate all integers with the following property.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> 123 , 1+2 = 3 , valid number
> 121224 12+12 = 24 , valid number
> 1235 1+2 = 3 , 2+3 = 5 , valid number
> 125 1+2 <5 , invalid number
> ```

Comment: SO is generally reluctant to solve your problems for you, much more willing to assist someone who has made an effort and got stuck.  and therein lies the lesson for you in your next interview: if you don't know the answer to a question of this sort, explain how you would start working out the answer, take the opportunity to show your problem solving skills in action, your knowledge of fundamental algorithms and of discrete mathematics.  Do all that and SO will pile in with assistance, though perhaps not during the interview itself.

Comment: The interview is over dude, chill out. I think questions like this are reasonable as long as they ask some algorithmic problem that might have a practical application.

Comment: Such questions are often designed to see how you'd approach a problem. Project Euler (http://projecteuler.net) has many such problems. In the absence of any kind of approach at all, start with the brute force approach and then add refinements once you've crafted the initial algorithm.

Comment: What constitutes a "valid number" is not properly specified, it's ambiguous.

Comment: I agree with phant0m. Do the component integers have to have the same number of digits? Does there only have to be two component numbers? For example, is 1+2+3 = 6  (1236) a valid number?

Comment: `1235 1+2 = 3 , 2+3 = 5 , valid number` this example makes me feel I can't spot the pattern.

Comment: It is this case that throws me : 121224 - the other valid cases look like fibonacci sequences.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I tried to solve this through dynamic programming and recursion.. Don't know where my answer landed but interviewer's face showed that the problem was too easy and I was screwing the solution.

Comment: @TylerDurden The problem looks challenging.. so i was curious for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways to accomplish this are:

1. Test every number in the input range to see if it qualifies.
2. Generate only those numbers that qualify. Use a nested loop for the two starting values, append the sum of the loop indexes to the loop indexes to come up with the qualifying number. Exit the inner loop when the appended number is past the upper limit.

The second method might be more computationally efficient, but the first method is simpler to write and maintain and is O(n).

I don't know what the interviewer is looking for, but I would suspect the ability to communicate is more important than the answer.

Comment: +1 for communication. The pattern isn't obvious to me. I bet they wanna see who jumps right into code hacking mode before having a proper specification.

Answer (score 1):

The naive way to solve this problem is by iterating the numbers in the set range, parsing the numbers into a digit sequence and then testing the sequence according to the rule. There is an optimization in that the problem essentially asks you to find fibonnaci numbers so you can use two variables or registers and add them sequentially.

It is unclear from your question whether the component numbers have to have the same number of digits. If not, then you will have to generate all the combinations of the component number arrangements.